# Migrate SharePoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, migration

Is it ok to migrate from a SQL Server 2005 db to SQL 2008 express on the new SharePoint 2010 server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's ok.

Just be aware of the limitations of SQL Server 2008 Express (max database sixe is 4GB per database; 10GB for SQL Server Express 2008 R2)

You want to upgrade Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 (with SQL Server 2008 express, which comes in with basic install.)

Migration Sharepoint is a big topic and there are many ways of achieving this.

One is described below:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=200

More resources on MSDN Blogs:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2010/01/31/sharepoint-2010-upgrade-key-resources.aspx